# Vritualenv is not getting activated with workon command

Tags: python, virtualenv

I made a virtualenv env by the following command

```
mkvirtualenv /var/www/env --system-sites-packages
```

When I run the command

```
workon env
```

Following error displayed

```
ERROR: Environment 'env' does not exist. Create it with 'mkvirtualenv env'
```

Comment: Have you tried `lsvirtualenv`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create `virtualenv` in `/var/www/env` to use workon

```
sudo chown <user> -R /var/www/
```

Then in `nano ~/.bashrc` and add following lines.

```
export WORKON_HOME=/var/www/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Then create `virtualenv`

```
mkvirtualenv env
```

Then to `activate`

```
workon env
```

I tested via `sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by error, create it with `'mkvirtualenv env'`.
You've created `/var/www/env` instead of `env` only

Comment: yeah, but i want env should be created inside /var/www directory

Comment: Then you're missing the point of virtualenvwrapper. That creates all the virtualenvs in the same place.

Comment: You can change the place where it creates `env` by changing the `WORKON_HOME` variable. By default it is `~/.virtualenvs`